# PHP script failing at submit: The Spam test doesn't work

Tags: php, html, forms

In this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2burL/1/ is my code for a PHP form.

CODE for working with the spam variables:

```
$human1 = mt_rand(0, 50); // random number to be written into this var
$human2 = mt_rand(0, 49); // same as $human1
$human_test = 0;  //declaration on the variable to be posted from the form
$spam_test = $human1 + $human2; // SUM the vars
```

CODE for testing:

```
$human_test = $_POST["human_test"];

    if (empty($_POST["human_test"]))
    {
        $humanerr = "This field is required.";
    }
    else if ($_POST["human_test"] != $spam_test)
    {
        $humanerr = "Wrong answer, try again.";
    }
    else
    {
    if ($_POST['submit'] && $test_error == 0 && $human_test == $spam_test)
    {
```

The problem is that when all required fields are set and posted at submit the "spam test" fails everytime no matter if the answer is right or wrong.

Syntax errors are not present. I've tested for the value of $spam_test and it is SUMed togehter, but the $_POST into the $human_test doesn't work somehow.

I get the `if` error that the inputed value is incorrect.

Does anyone see the error in my code? Or does anyone have a good way to test where the error lies?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: please post your tried code here.

Comment: Perhaps drawing a simple picture/diagram of what you want the end result to look like would make it easier to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it seems that there is something you don't understand, you can use the css rule
**margin: 0px auto;** for the div you want to be centered...
Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LN5Zs/

```
<div style="height:150px; width:150px; background:red; margin:0px auto;">
<div style="height:150px; width:100px; background:yellow; margin:0px auto;">
    <div style="height:150px; width:80px; background:blue; margin:0px auto;">centered div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's probably best to avoid inline styling ;-)

Comment: The center one is centered. I want all the other to be like 3 on the left of the centered, 3 on the right and one right under it.

Comment: @Nick R You can obviously paste the inline styling rules to your stylesheet and remove them from your markup. I just wanted to quickly make my point.
iNejc: I'm working on a possible solution...

Comment: Check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/LN5Zs/4/
It's really not an elegant solution but it might help you.

Comment: @ArxontasTouSkotous thank you. you got exactly what I was asking! You the man.

Comment: @iNejc You're welcome. However, try to be more specific next time and with some more info e.g. a diagram. Otherwise, most guys in here will offend you, and you won't get any answer EVEN IF they finally understood what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use float left and right foer the side elements and absolute position the centre DIV, it will really depend on what you are tyring to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with absolute positioning. Make your wrapper div a `position:relative`, and the inner divs `position:absolute`. Then you can set their x and y positioning as you please, and keep the central div at `top:0; left:0;`

So it would be:
**div to the right** - `top:0; left:100%;`
**div to the left** - `top:0; right:100%;`
**div to the top** - `bottom:100%; left:0;`
**div to the bottom** - `top:100%; left:0;`

Here's a working fiddle, providing an example of the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/tGYze/